# Get time from time zone using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

i need to print actual time from timezone using node js. iam using moment-timezone to find out the time from time zones.

This is my code

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

console.log(moment().tz("UTC+05:30").format());
console.log(moment().tz("UTC+05").format());
console.log(moment().tz("UTC−04:30").format());
console.log(moment().tz("UTC+08").format());
console.log(moment().tz("UTC+06").format());
```

But i got result like this

```
Moment Timezone has no data for UTC+05:30. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.
2016-03-09T16:31:10+05:30
Moment Timezone has no data for UTC+05. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.
2016-03-09T16:31:10+05:30
Moment Timezone has no data for UTC−04:30. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.
2016-03-09T16:31:10+05:30
Moment Timezone has no data for UTC+08. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.
2016-03-09T16:31:10+05:30
Moment Timezone has no data for UTC+06. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.
2016-03-09T16:31:10+05:30
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: its not possible for me. bcse , its can be any country's time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the documentation, `moment.tz([string])` expects `[string]` to be in the `'Country/City'` format, and does NOT accept `UTC+XX` formats.

Use `moment().utcOffset([string])` to apply UTC offsets before formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Following your question, you can use:

```
moment().utcOffset(520).format() // for UTC+5:30
```